# Where do I file bugs for the Ubuntu One music client for Android?

Tags: ubuntu-one, android

I've recently started using the Ubuntu One Music [streaming client](https://one.ubuntu.com/mobile/) for Android. From the web page it says that the android app is based on [Subsonic](http://www.subsonic.org/pages/index.jsp).

I want to file bugs on the app, mostly feature requests and things like that, and from looking at [the screenshots](http://www.subsonic.org/pages/apps.jsp#android), the application seems to be Subsonic preconfigured to use my U1 music collection.

Is it appropriate for me to file feature requests with Subsonic, or is there a Launchpad project where we're supposed to file bugs which are then vetted and sent upstream?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're best to file bugs against our client; yes, it's based on the Subsonic Android client, but there are a number of changes. The Ubuntu One client is in Launchpad at https://launchpad.net/ubuntuone-android-music.

Comment: Oops, thanks for pointing out my mistake - I hereby withdraw my answer.